# kill a running application using mobile substrate - iphone?

Tags: iphone

I need to kill a running application on iPhone using mobile substrate.Can anybody help me to do so? Or just give me an idea if it is possible or not / if possible how ?

Looking forward ..

Thanks
Syam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `exit(0)` whenever you want to terminate the application through code

Edited: (answered by syam)

```
Class $SBApplicationController=objc_getClass("SBApplicationController") SBApplication *app=[[$SBApplicationController sharedInstance] applicationWithDisplayIdentifier:displayIdentfier]; 
if(app) [app kill];
```

hAPPY cODING...

Comment: Hey..Thanks for the response..but I need to kill the application from another application which runs in background...am using jailbroken iphone..also I am able to use mobilesubstrate..Any Idea?

Comment: Class $SBApplicationController=objc_getClass("SBApplicationController") SBApplication *app=[[$SBApplicationController sharedInstance] applicationWithDisplayIdentifier:displayIdentfier];           if(app)
  [app kill];

Comment: good dat your problem got solved.. bt can i know the reason for downvote?

Comment: Ok..We are able to get the application display identifier by using spring board header methods.. using the display identifier we get the current application instance.once we get the application instance you can directly kill the application by calling the method kill...

Comment: I need to kill the app from another app...exit(0) is called from the app itself...

Comment: okay so dats the reason for downvote. :O ....  Actually i dint saw the word mobile substrate before so.... :)